# how to hide CDialogEX from taskbar? (MFC C++)

Tags: c++, mfc, taskbar, cdialog

I have the main-frame, when someone is pressing a button I open a CDialogEX.

After I open it, it get's an empty task-bar tab, with no title or icon...

i want it to open as a child window of the main-frame and without task-bar tab.

i have tried using styles and stuff, but nothing works.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are passing `NULL` as the parent window. Pass the window handle of your main application's window. When you pass `NULL` the created window is an unowned top-level window and they get taskbar buttons.

Comment: you'r idea was good, but the thing that solved my problem was that somone put in the StyleEX() function: WS_EX_APPWINDOW   Forces a top-level window onto the taskbar when the window is visible. FLAG...

i have just removed it and it is working...
as for the parent, i did as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Some bibliography for you:

- http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/frameworks/advancedui/article.php/c3227
- http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-442093.html
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/2d2ef9ad-487b-43d2-997b-e0c2540064d6/
- http://www.progtown.com/topic62404-hide-mainframe-from-taskbar.html
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191/Creating-an-application-with-no-taskbar-icon

Now the real work. Declare a

```
CWnd m_wndHidden;
```

in your class.

Then implement the following method

```
BOOL CMyMDIChildFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs) 
{ 
     if (!__super::PreCreateWindow(cs))
         return FALSE;

     // Create hidden window
     if (!::IsWindow(m_wndHidden.m_hWnd))
     {
        pstrOwnerClass = AfxRegisterWndClass(0);
        if (!m_wndHidden.CreateEx(0, pstrOwnerClass, _T(""), WS_POPUP,
                CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                NULL, 0))
            return FALSE;
     }

    cs.hwndParent = m_wndHidden.m_hWnd;
    return TRUE;
}
```

The first and last link I provided are based on this approach.